# windows phone 7 does not receive scripts and js files on https

Tags: windows-phone-7, jquery-mobile, https

Can't solve a problem that I have regarding windows phone jquery mobile https and asp.net mvc 2. I have a asp.net mvc 2 app that resides on my localhost. Some pages require https connection, so when I use my windows phone to browse through pages everything is fine (jquery mobile renders fine) until I accept the https message and go to the https page then it showes all html content with no javascript and css (white background with black text, jquery mobile not working, hidden divs now visible and so on). Seems like windows phone is blocking the files on https in this particular scenatio. Quite strange problem, especially that everything works on Iphone. Iphone renders everything just fine whether its http or https. 
I'm not gonna try to paste any code since I don't event know where to start, and the app is too large to paste code snippets. Just wanted to know if anyone had similar problem, or has any idea how to overcome this issue.

Thanks.

EDIT: by searching through forums I stumbled upon problem of self signed certificate on the server and accesing pages with windows phone, dont know if this is the exact problem tho

Answer (score 0):

I think I found solution to my problem, as I thought I need to add the same self signed certificate to my phone that I generated on the server. It is not necessary on the iphone, but for some reason Windows Phone requiers it.